# Java Arrays not accepting values

Tags: java, arrays

Arrays are not taking in values and setting the values to 0 only by default. I used debugger and saw that nothing changes when i feed in values. I have never experienced this. I am using Java SE13 in Code OSS. OS Arch Linux

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A_Little_Elephant_and_Rozdil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        // int[] brr = new int[n];
        
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        // for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        //     arr[i] = brr[i];
        // }

        // Arrays.sort(arr);
        // if(arr[0]==arr[1])
        //     {
        //         System.out.println("Still Rozdil");
        //         in.close();
        //         return;
        //     }
        // else{
        //     for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        //         if(arr[0] == brr[i])
        //             {
        //                 System.out.println(i+1);

        //                 in.close();
        //                 return;
        //             }
        //     }

        // }
        
        in.close();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: why you have commented your code?

Comment: Did you mean to say, after getting input in ```arr[i]```. All ```arr[i]``` are coming up as ```0```?. Have you verified this by ```sysout```?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue - you should try to print the contents of your array using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` after the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probable cause of your problem is the commented `for` loop in which you are doing

```
arr[i] = brr[i];
```

`brr[i]` will be zero in each iteration of the loop because you never set any values in `brr` array. So after second loop executes, all the values inside `arr` will be overwritten with zeroes.